# Background Image Overlapped Problem with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

[Here is my working page](http://aafggucb.facebook.joyent.us/chess.html). I attached buttons to white bishop and you can move around but left images are overlapped by right images. I think the problem is with CSS. The brief structure is here.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#top').click(function(){
                $('#p81').animate({top: "-=64px"}, 100);
            });
</script>
<style>
        div.chess_board{
            height: 512px;
            position: relative;
            width: 512px;
        }
        div.chess_square{
            height:64px;
            position: absolute;
            width:64px;
        }
        div.chess_square.white {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
        }
            .
            .
            .
        div.chess_piece{
                background-image: url("sprite.png");
                height: 64px;
                width: 64px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        div.chess_piece.bishot.white{
            background-position: -64px 0;           
        }
</style>

<div class="chess_board">
  <div id="b81" class="chess_square white" style="top: 448px; left: 64px;">
    <div class="chess_square_inner"></div>
    <div id="p81" class="chess_piece bishot white"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="top" value="top" />
```

Comment: Can you put up an online example? This is awfully difficult to imagine in one's head. And, as a ground rule, I'd recommend putting `&nbsp;`s into those DIVs so they get properly rendered in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply Pekka. I already put the link http://aafggucb.facebook.joyent.us/chess.html Please have a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the overlap effect because you are using a transparent PNG. When you move the position of the bishop over, it simple moves on top of the rook. You can do one of the following:

1. Double up your sprite to have the white and gray backgrounds. Then switch to the appropriate space. The PNG will not be transparent so you will cover it up.
2. You can update your jQuery to hide the background of the destination, in this case the rook.

Example for item 2: (You will have to get crafty with your selectors)

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    $(piece).animate({left: "-=64px"}, 100);
    $("#p80").css("background-image", "none");
});
```

**UPDATE**

After looking at your page a bit more you can also resolve it by setting the background color of the div with class 'chess_piece'.

```
.chess_piece
{
    background-color: #ffffff/#cfcfcf;
}
```

You could do it with jQuery and your event:

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    $(piece).animate({left: "-=64px"}, 100);
    $(piece).css("background-color", "#cfcfcf");
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

After seeing your comment, the issue has changed slightly. To overcome that issue you need to add a `z-index` to your piece. The generated markup would be something like:

```
<div class="chess_piece bishot white" id="p81" style="top: -64px; left: 64px; z-index: 10000;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Durilai. But I'm not so good at CSS so could you please show me one line of code?

Comment: It still doesn't solve my problem. I forgot to say that real problem is 'Top' and 'Right' div. Can you please have a look again my site and click on 'Top' and 'Right' buttons? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: When I click top and then right the bishop disappears. Is that the problem you are referring to?

Comment: Yes exactly! If you need source code, you may see it in your browser. I've tried much but still not working :(

Comment: You know what, durilai! You are amazing :D Exactly What I'm expecting. Really Really thank you so much!